# How modify a K8s pod descriptor without restarting it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to modify a Kubernetes pod descriptor postponing the restart to a later event?

Basically I want to defer the changes to scheduled restart event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. That is not a feature of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

[Pod Presets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/) can work for cases where you want to inject additional configuration in the pod specification at creation time. Think of them as templates / blueprints that are used to inject additional configuration in the pods that match the specified labels, at creation time. You can have a look at some use cases [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/).